# Appium - The Certificate used to sign "WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner" has either expired or has been revoked

Tags: ios, xcode, appium

Appium Desktop: 1.21.0
iPhone 6: iOS 12.4.8 (update 12.5.5 pending but not installed)
MacBook: 11.6

Hello,

I am trying to run a script on the iPhone 6. I was able to run it on several apps before the new year, and now when I try to run it I get several errors in the Appium log.

I have not updated anything on the Mac, or Appium, or the iPhone, or the app itself. I'm thinking maybe something expired in the new year but I don't know what or where. The errors are talking about certificates but I'm not sure where to look for that. The App team say nothing has changed on their side.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

> installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:
> failed  with { [Xcode] NSLocalizedDescription = "Unable to install
> "WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner""; [Xcode]
> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "The certificate used to  sign
> "WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner" has either expired or has been
> revoked. An updated certificate is required to sign and install the
> application.";
> [Xcode] NSUnderlyingError = "Error
> Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402620392  "The
> identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid."
>
> [Xcode] ), DVTRadarComponentKey=487925,  NSLocalizedDescription=The
> identity used to sign the executable is no  longer valid.}},
> NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to install
> "WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner", NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The
> certificate used to sign "WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner" has either
> expired or has been revoked. An updated certificate is required to
> sign  and install the application.}
>
> [Xcode] No signing certificate "iOS Development" found: No "iOS
> Development" signing certificate matching team ID "********" with a
> private key was found. [Xcode] No profiles for
> 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner.xctrunner'  were found: Xcode
> couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning  profiles matching
> 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner.xctrunner'.  Automatic signing is
> disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable  automatic
> signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild
>
> automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.
> [Xcode] WebDriverAgentRunner: [Xcode] WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner
> encountered an error (Failed  to install or launch the test runner. If
> you believe this error represents a  bug, please attach the result
> bundle at /Users/testingmacbook2/Library/
> Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgentfvxubjhhmibljkavzmyifigxrumc/Logs/Test/TestWebDriverAgentRunner-2022.01.05_10-40-25-+0000.xcresult.
> (Underlying Error: Unable to install "WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner".
> The  certificate used to sign "WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner" has either
> expired or has been revoked. An updated certificate is required to
> sign  and install the application. (Underlying Error: The identity
> used to sign the  executable is no longer valid.))) [Xcode]  [Xcode]
> ** TEST EXECUTE FAILED ** [Xcode]  [Xcode]  [Xcode] Testing started [Xcode]  [WebDriverAgent] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal
> 'null'

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of target signing & Capabilities  ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix.
It appears the provisioning profile I set up had expired. So I set up a new one using the Basic (manual) configuration method found on this website.
https://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/#basic-manual-configuration